# Is it possible to (de)activate a specific set of cells in jupyter?

Tags: jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook and I would like to perform several runs, the code I want to run depending on the results of the previous runs. I divided my notebook into several cells, and for each run I would like to select which cell should be executed and which one should not. Is there a functionality which looks like "run all cells except those I explicitly deactivate"?

Comment: You can use Freeze notebook extension to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to DataScience.SE!

This is not currently possible. You could change the cells to *Raw*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a condition at the cost of one extra indentation.

```
cellEnabled = 0
#cellEnabled = 1

if cellEnabled:
    doA()
    doB()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two methods that come to mind are to use 'm' [convert to markdown], and then 'y' to reactivate it [convert to code], or to just use the comment function: Ctrl+a to highlight everything in the cell and Ctrl+/ to uniformly comment, or uncomment, the code.